# How to use RecyclerView and CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I don't have much experience in android development and try to implement RecyclerView in my application. The version of android studio does not have Android L neither there is option to install. Everytime it says `android.support.widget.v7.RecyclerView` in not used and disabled it from import packages. I give refrences in layout file also in Gradle.build but my problem is still there anyone help please?

Comment: Please post your gradle.build. and xml layouts your using to implement the recycler view.

Comment: You should update your SDK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this line

- CardView and RecyclerView in Material Design

http://icetea09.com/blog/2014/12/19/android-cardview-and-recyclerview-in-material-design/

add these into the **dependencies**:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

and update the `gradle` in module's `build.gradle`

- Example for each one:

**`CardView`**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:contentPadding="16dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content here" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**RecyclerView:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i've just add other information for this reply, the link maybe disabled in the future and this is the reason.

Comment: what is the reason AndroidDev ?

Comment: that link maybe disabled in the future. so @AndroidDev wants to add example.

Comment: but your ans solve my problem. Thanks for the help. accepting your ans

Comment: @abhishek please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393540/no-shadow-elevation-underneath-second-card-if-there-are-two-card-in-the-layout

Answer (score 2):

**EXPLANATION OF HOW YOU CAN USE RECYCLER VIEW IN ANDROID**

Here are the steps with the explanation how you can use Recycler View

- go to app gradle file
- add the dependency for Recycler View
  `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'` (Use latest one dependency at the time you are creating your project) , and sync the project
- in your activity/ fragment file use the Recycler View with  this tag -- recyler view is available in v7 widget support files
- go to you respective Java File and get a reference to this recycler view
- create a new layout (xml) file to create the custom view you want to infilate in your recyler view and name it like **custom_row.xml** .
- Create a Java class and name it **RecyclerviewHolder** and extend it with RecyclerView.ViewHolder and create an super constructor , and then get access to all the views in your custom-row.xml file
- now create an another Java class named **RecylerAdapter** or **MyRecyclerAdapter** and extend it by **RecyclerView.Adapter** and pass your **RecyclerviewHolder** class here like

  **`class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewHolder>`**
- and then create one constructor and just press alt+enter it will generate three methods for you , i.e. you just need to override these three methods of **RecyclerView.Adapter class**

these three methods are :-

**{ onCreateViewHolder  , OnBindViewHolder  , getCount }**

- **OnCreateViewHolder**  - a method where you will pass your custom view layout to infilate it with LayoutInflater and in this method only you need to create an Object of **RecyclerviewHolder** class also after that you will return                           this view object in this method .
- **OnBindViewHolder**    - you can perform any action here on your views just prefix holder. to all your views name and use them to perform any action or for any event handling
- **getCount**  - here we will return the value of count how many time you want to infilate your custom view
- now go to your respectve Activity or Fragment File and create one object of **RecyclerAdapter** Class and set this adapter on your recycler view .

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) you have to add specials dependencies to your gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'

}
```

To use it, always prefix with `android.support.v7.widget.`

Comment: @AndroidDev just updated, documentation is not updated

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView uses an Adapter, which passes List items to it. The adapter returns an object of the type of List Item you choose to pass to the RecyclerView. In this post, you will learn how to implement RecyclerView in your app, and how to pass CardView objects to scroll through them.

Steps:
1) Build a CardView
2) Build a data model to populate your CardView
3) Build a RecyclerView
4) Build an adapter connecting your data to the RecyclerView
5) Set the adapter to your RecyclerView

This tutorial will help you take these steps to use RecyclerView and CardView in your Android app:

https://knowledgecollisions.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/using-recyclerview-and-cardview-in-your-android-app/

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Recyclerview* without *CardView*.But *CardView* gives more features to design the list row.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29+'
```

Changed version according to your `targetSdkVersion` in `build.grade(:app)` file, in my case it's `29`