# ListView using CardView + RecyclerView is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am new to android ,Here i trying to bind ListView by using RecyclerView and Cardview .In my case I didn't get any errors but I could not get the ListView items.

This is my adapter class

RecyclerviewAdapter_list.java

```
public class RecyclerviewAdapter_list extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter_list.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<myAlarms> myAlarmsdata;

    public RecyclerviewAdapter_list(Context mContext, List<myAlarms>myAlarms){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.myAlarmsdata =myAlarms;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_alarm, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myAlarms myAlarms =myAlarmsdata.get(position);
        holder.mTime.setText(myAlarmsdata.get(position).getALARM_TIME());
        holder.mTitle.setText(myAlarmsdata.get(position).getALARM_TITLE());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myAlarmsdata.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTime,mTitle,mAmPm;
        SwitchButton mbtn;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mTime);
          //  mAmPm = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mAmPm);
            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mTitle);
          //  mbtn = (SwitchButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mTime);

        }
    }
}
```

AlarmActivity.java

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView mAddIcon;
    List<myAlarms>myAlarms;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Database_Helper database_helper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.StatusbarColor);

        database_helper = new Database_Helper(this);
        mAddIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mAddIcon);
        myAlarms = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView_id);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        RecyclerviewAdapter_list recyclerviewAdapter_list =new RecyclerviewAdapter_list(this,myAlarms);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerviewAdapter_list);



        mAddIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<myAlarms> myAlarms = database_helper.getMyAlarms();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, CreateAlarm.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_out);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I need to do the changes and where I did the mistakes .
Thanks.

Comment: attach debugger to this line `List<myAlarms> myAlarms = database_helper.getMyAlarms();` and see if you get any data, you only triger this line when you click a button, if you don't your adapter will set null

Answer (score 0):

I add the same problem before, a solution is to remove your CardView and just add this line to a Layout:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

This drawable has exactly the same design than a CardView. Besides, you don't need any implementation to use it so you can remove your CardView implementation from Gradle.

You can also check this : [How to use RecyclerView and CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377100/how-to-use-recyclerview-and-cardview)

Answer (score 0):

You put this code in your project

//when you want horizontal
 layoutManager.setOrientation(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

//when you want vertical
 layoutManager.setOrientation(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);

Comment: Are you answering the question above?