# Gradle error while adding the dependencies CardView and RecylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin, android-cardview

I am trying to implement a cardView, where when the user presses the FAB, a cardView is created dynamically. However, when I put the following bit of code in the gradle dependencies, I get an error:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
```

> It says 'This support library should not use a different version  (23)
>   than the compileSdkversion 27.

Currently, my apk level is 16.

What's the problem?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377100/how-to-use-recyclerview-and-cardview/48139515#48139515

Comment: change to implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1' and implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: don't use + in version at implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
for version use proper version name like 27.1.1 instead 23.0.+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace with this dependency in your Gradle.build:

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have used `compileSdkversion 27`. So you need to update dependency to `27`.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Don't try to use `+` sign for integrating dependency.